# How to query Products by Opportunity?

Tags: soql, opportunity

I want to query products only related to particular opportunity. And I tried this using sub-queries but I was able to retrieve PricebookEntries related to Opportunities. I'll hit a dead end if I tried joining the results with Product2. 
How to go about this?

```
SELECT Id from Product2 where Id in ( 
   SELECT Product2Id  
   FROM PricebookEntry 
   WHERE Pricebook2Id in (Select Pricebook2Id FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Closed') 
)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [OpportunityLineItem](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm) to traverse from Opportunity to PricebookEntry and Product..

something like this query

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, 
  (SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, 
   PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family FROM 
   OpportunityLineItems) 
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :YourOppId
```

You can also refer [this object model](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) to understand the relationship between Product, Pricebook, OpportunityLineItem and Opportunity objects

Comment: i was only 1 minute off...sigh

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks, please how do I select all fields from product2 ?

Comment: there is no Select * .. so you have to include the fields you want in the query. you can check the product2 object for all the available fields and add them in.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
select id, quantity, unitPrice, totalPrice, productCode, product2.someFldOnProduct2, 
       opportunity.name, opportunity.amount, opportunity.somefieldOnOppo
    from OpportunityLineItem 
    where opportunity.stageName = 'Closed'
```

You need to be at Version 30 or higher to do this as the lookup relationship from `OpportunityLineItem` to `Product2` didn't exist until then.

*Grouping / aggregating omitted from the above, exercise left to the reader; you could also do summarization/grouping in Apex*