# Conga Composer: Query Salesforce Files from Products to Opportunity

Tags: query, files, conga-composer

A button on an opportunity should bring all salesforce files from the related products. Trying to figure out the correct query for this

What i have found so far is the query for salesforce files:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.id 
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '{pv0}'
```

And how to query products to opportunities:

[How to query Products by Opportunity?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73116/how-to-query-products-by-opportunity)

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, 
  (SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, 
   PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family FROM 
   OpportunityLineItems) 
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :YourOppId
```

My tuition is that i should combine these two somehow:

Something like:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN
(SELECT PricebookEntry.Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE Opportunity = ‘{pv0}’)
```

But I get an error that

> The inner select field 'PricebookEntry.Product2Id' cannot have more
>   than one level of relationships

Any ideas how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you cannot specify related fields in the inner SELECT statement -- you can only specify fields that are in the object itself.

There is a Product2Id field in the OpportunityLineItem object (see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm)) so you should be able to use this field:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.Id FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN
(SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{pv0}')
```

Comment: Thanks

I tried to add the query but I am still getting an error:

ERROR at Row:1:Column:100
sObject type 'OpportunityLineItems' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.

I tried without s on opportunitylineitems but still error:

ERROR at Row:1:Column:126
No such column 'Opportunity' on entity 'OpportunityLineItem'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name.

What can I try next?

Comment: Sorry I had a couple typos in that line, I've corrected them.  FYI there is a [document object reference here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm).