# Retrieving Parent Account from OpportunityLineItems

Tags: sql, developer

I've made a few attempts to pull an opportunity field (`Bill_To_Account__c` from line items. I came across [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73116/how-to-query-products-by-opportunity#) but can't figure out the solution.

### Attempt 1

```
SELECT Id, Forecast_Start_Date__c, Forecast_End_Date__c, Forecast_Product_Name__c, 
Name, OpportunityId, (SELECT Bill_To_Account__c FROM Opportunity)
FROM OpportunityLineItem
```

The error:

```
INVALID_TYPE:
(SELECT Bill_To_Account__c FROM Opportunity)
^
```

### Attempt 2

```
SELECT Id, Forecast_Start_Date__c, Forecast_End_Date__c, Forecast_Product_Name__c, 
Name, OpportunityId, Opportunity__r.Bill_To_Account__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
```

The error:

```
INVALID_FIELD:
Forecast_Product_Name__c, Name, OpportunityId, Opportunity__r.Bill_To_Account__c
^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt 2 should work, but you should try `Opportunity.Bill_To_Account__c` instead of `Opportunity__r.Bill_To_Account__c` since it's not a custom relationship.

Comment: That did it! Thank you :)